# Why does qt object::connect() say there is no instance of overloaded function "QDialog_subclass::connect"?

Tags: c++, qt

In the constructor for a class I have (which is a sub-class of QDialog and has a QWidget as a parent), I am attempting to create a signal-slot connection between it's parent, and a member object that it instantiates.

```
loadLib1::loadLib1(Qwidget* parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
   // Declare members
   ...
   m_animationFrame = new AnimationFrame(this);
   if (0 !=m_animationFrame)
   {
      connect(parent, &wndWidget::loadToggled, m_animationFrame, &AnimationFrame::slotCreateWidget);
   }
}
```

Visual Studio highlights it and says:

```
*no instance of overloaded function "loadLib1::connect" matches the argument list
argument types are: (QWidget *, void (wndWidget::*)(), AnimationFrame *, void (AnimationFrame::*)())*
```

Note: wndWidget(from QMainWindow) and AnimationFrame(from QFrame) are classes.

It seems to me like this should work, based on the Qt documentation and examples. Any idea why it is not?

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
connect(parent, &wndWidget::loadToggled, m_animationFrame, &AnimationFrame::slotCreateWidget);
```

`parent` is QWidget pointer. QWidget does not have signal loadToggled. Solution, change parameter type:

```
loadLib1::loadLib1(wndWidget* parent) : QDialog(parent)
```

---

Alternatively, use `qobject_cast` to cast `parent` to `wndWidget` pointer. Remember to check if cast succeeds (use temp variable). But it is better to just change the parameter type, so you get compile error if types don't match, instead of needing to handle situation at runtime.